# My toggleClass function only sometimes works on my JSON-created fields when the cache is hard-reloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm creating a website for use with my tabletop gaming group, designed to show details of various npc's, items, etc. I have the data stored in a JSON file, which is being read correctly and storing each object as a separate article within their own div, which by default don't display their data. When clicked, each article is supposed to expand to show the objects details, but my toggleClass function only works occasionally, and usually only after a hard-reload.

I've tried appending the toggleClass to the end of the .js that reads the JSON, but to no avail (don't know why that doesn't work). So far, I've been getting the best results with using a $(window)on.("load", clickLoad('article')) to call the script, but after a regular refresh and occasionally for no reason at all, the script simply fails to toggle the class. I don't know whats going wrong.

I call the script at the end of the body with this:

`<script>$(window).on("load", clickLoad('article'))</script>`

My clickLoad function looks like this:

```
function clickLoad(clickClass) {
  $(clickClass).click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass( "click" );
  })
}
```

In theory this should load at the end every time and successfully add the class name "click" to the article, which then is displayed following my css rules. However, in practice this only happens some of the time and forces me and my players to use developer tools to hard-reload a couple times until it works correctly.

Comment: Update: By placing the function itself at the end of the body instead of calling it from an external file, the browser no longer puts the script in its cache. Now it works without a hard-reload being required, though it still doesn't work every time. Is there a way to delay loading the script more than using $(window).on("load", ...)?

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
function clickLoad(clickClass) {
      $(clickClass).click(function() {
          $(clickClass).toggleClass( "click" );
      })
    }
```

Comment: Changing $(this) to $(clickClass) doesn't work. It not only has the same problem of only having intermittent success and usually needing a hard reload, but it causes it to apply to all articles instead of only the item clicked, which defeats the purpose of the script. The script as written works, but only sometimes, and usually only if I empty the cache and force it to hard reload. Do you have any other ideas why this is happening?